# Python - strange interaction between exec and timeit functions

Tags: python, pandas, timeit

I'm trying to write a script that will time another script on a line by line basis.

So far i've coded a loop that should ideally return a dataframe showing the time taken to execute each line in a script:

```
import pandas
import numpy
Py_file = open("test execute.py").readlines()
Timer = pandas.DataFrame([])
i = 0
while i < len(Py_file):
        Timer = Timer.append([[i,numpy.average(timeit.timer('exec(Py_file[0])', globals = globals()).repeat(5))]])
        exec(Py_file[0])
```

The issue is with this line segment:

`timeit.timer('exec(Py_file[0])', globals = globals()).repeat(5)`

If I run the exec statement by itself a single line might take 0.1 seconds per iteration. When I run that same line inside the timeit.timer function it takes ~ 12-15 seconds per iteration.

I'd appreciate some help explaining this unexpected behaviour and coming up with a more robust solution if possible.

Comment: use a proper profiler like https://github.com/csurfer/pyheat

Comment: thanks Alex. Couldn't get some functions to work (e.g. show_heatmap()) but its viewable inside the console when I create the heatmap.